# Consistent spacing in boxplots with different numbers of x labels

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to make boxplot consisting of a variable number (2-4) of boxes. When I generate them without any extra settings, the plot depicting 2 boxes is much more spaced out and the boxes are narrower, compared to the plot depicting 4 boxes.

I've been able to get the box width consistent using the `width` parameter, but the general plot is more spaced out in the 2-box plot vs the 4-box plot.

I would like to have two plots that look consistent, i.e. same box size, same spacing to the left edge and between the boxes and same scale generally.

Sample code for what I have so far:

```
##1st plot with four groups to be plotted on x axis
#some random data
plot_data=[]
for i in range(4):
    plot_data.append([random.randint(39,80) for j in range(10)])

plt.boxplot(plot_data,widths=0.45)
plt.show()

##2nd plot with with two groups to be plotted on x axis
#some random data
plot_data=[]
for i in range(2):
    plot_data.append([random.randint(39,80) for j in range(10)])

plt.boxplot(plot_data,widths=0.45/(4/len(plot_data)))
plt.show()
```

4-box boxplot:

[image]

2-box boxplot:

[image]

2-box boxplot with just `widths=0.45`

[image]

Comment: Why are you using `widths=0.45/(4/len(plot_data))` instead of `widths=0.45` for the second plot?  Note that your requirement *"I would like to have two plots that look consistent, i.e. same box size, same spacing to the left edge and between the boxes and same scale generally."* seems mathematically complicated. You can change the width of the second plot, but then the two figures look quite different.  Or you can set some empty space inside the second plot via `plt.xlim(0.5, 4.5)` (but using `widths=0.45` in the call to `plt.boxplot()`).

Comment: Also note that you can insert images via <control>B.  While you are a new user, these images will be inserted as a link.  Usually a moderator pops in and adds that image directly to the post.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try that.
`widths=0.45` caused the boxes to become quite large relative to the axis labels. I found that scaling it by the maximum number of boxes I would have (4 in my case) gave me the result I want, except for the spacing around the boxes.

Comment: Using xlim and a constant widths actually looks quite nice, thank you. Lots of empty space to the right, but I suppose I could cut that part of the plot off.